# cant get my div to stay the same opacity when flipped

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im a pretty new coder using flippy.js and when my navigation button is clicked  i want the div to flip but stay the same color/opacity once the flip has been executed but have new content within it(already achieved that), so it begins the flip fine, but then dissappears midway,  i have tried a few different methods like onfinish, content, that i have found on stack overflow but cant seem to find the solution to my issue any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

CODE:

```
function about(){

$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".flipbox").flippy({
            color_target : "rgba(66,66,66,.6)", 
            direction : "LEFT",
            duration : "750",
            verso : function(){$(".flipbox").load("hello.html")},
          });
      });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flipbox">


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flipbox{

    width: 760px;
    height: 460px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#666;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position:relative;
    border: .3px solid black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 2px 2px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 2px #ccc;
        box-shadow:         3px 3px 2px 2px #ccc;


    }
```

Comment: This is one of the unfortunate things about using JQuery add-ons blindly. You have no idea what the code does (and neither do we), so you'll need to dig in to the source of the add on to see what's going wrong.

Alternately, you could find a different plug in, or try it with CSS3 and standard JQuery.

Comment: Also, inspect the element .flipbox after you've triggered the function. Does the class name change?